# How to loop through nested objects in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Since this in an object i doing this but it doesn't work. 
How would I get the 'key' field through a loop?

```
  <div>
      <ul>
        {tickets && tickets.issues && Object.keys(tickets.issues).map((issue, i) =>
        (
          <li key={i}>
            Issue number: {tickets.issues.key}
          </li>
         ))}
      </ul>
  </div>
```

**SOLUTION**

```
   <div>
      <ul>
       {this.state.tickets && this.state.tickets.issues && Object.keys(this.state.tickets.issues).map((issue, i) =>
       (
        <li key={i}>
           Issue number: {this.state.tickets.issues[i].key}
        </li>
      ))}
      </ul>
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: There is only one array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your response image the key field exists in issues[] but not in fields, so it should be fine just (no nesting required):

```
{ Object.keys(tickets.issues).map((issue, i) => (
  <li key={issue.key}>
   Issue number: {issue.key}
  </li>
))}
```

If you have the key in fields (not expanded in the image)

```
{ Object.keys(tickets.issues).map((issue, i) => (
  Object.keys(issue.fields).map(field=>(
 <li key={field.key}>
   Issue number: { field.key }
 </li>
)
))}
```

Comment: Hmm using the first method where tickets.issues is an array, not relating to fields, i get an error, **TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object**

Comment: hmm, test if they exist, `{tickets && tickets.issues && Object.keys(...)}` because they only becomes available after api call.

Comment: Yeah.. I see what's happening now, it renders before i fetch my JSON data in my **componentDidMount** function, how do i go from there, that's why the object is null. Is there a way to get the data before it renders?

Comment: No. You must check as I commented above.

Comment: Okay done i did it and yeah it seems to be empty, nothing is being printed

Comment: I edited ur code to show what i did and nothing prints, there's not error this time though

Comment: What should I do now :O

Comment: I will post my solution o.o

Comment: ha, you were getting object from state. okay.

Comment: yeahh but its weird because before rendering i initialized tickets to var tickets = this.state XD

Comment: It was a dumb mistake XDDDD

Comment: No problem, it happens sometimes to me either.

Comment: Hey i seem to be stuck again, here's the link :-( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52596543/reactjs-json-object-stuck-trying-to-display-the-data-within-a-nested-json-obj/52596613?noredirect=1#comment92128770_52596613

Comment: Sorry, I just see this and going to sleep. If you don't get answer, then I'll provide tomorrow. But you should get idea in my answer as well. Look at the second code and try to understand what it is doing.

Comment: Hey I have a question, what if I had to put the **<li key={index}> </li> in the outer loop** and the **issue number in the inner loop**, how would the syntax look like? Thanks.

Comment: `{ Object.keys(tickets.issues).map((issue, i) => (
  <li>
  {
    Object.keys(issue.fields).map(field=>(
      {field.key}
    )
  }
  </li>
))}`

Answer (score 2):

`tickets.issues` is an Array of Objects, so:

```
const { issues } = tickets;
issues.map(issue => console.log(issue.key));
```

Comment: Let me try this :D

Comment: How would i display it in the render function?

Comment: Not on the Mount function

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution

```
  <div>
    <ul>
      {tickets && tickets.issues && Object.keys(tickets.issues).map((issue, i) => 
     (
      <li key={i}>
         Issue number: {tickets.issues.key}
      </li>
    ))}
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: It doesn't display anything o.o

Comment: It should work now I made small mistake. Please check the updated answer

Comment: Still nothing o.o

Comment: Ohh i just realized theres no fields

Comment: It's only tickets.issues.

Comment: @leojrsilao Hooo ok your OP was nested with fields. Np. You added your solution on top of mine so I edited again and added your solution alone to my answer. Feel free to edit Will approve if you need

Comment: With my solution, the data still doesn't display :/, its empty theres no data being shown

Comment: Hey I seem to be stuck again :/ can you check my problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52596543/reactjs-json-object-stuck-trying-to-display-the-data-within-a-nested-json-obj/52596613?noredirect=1#comment92128770_52596613