# Reactjs / JSON object, stuck trying to display the data within a nested JSON object

Tags: json, reactjs, object

I am stuck trying to display a certain value in a nested object in reactjs. This approach i'm using works for the a one nested object as follows:

**CODE DOESN'T WORK, UNABLE TO DISPLAY THIS DATA(Unable to fetch the data from customfield_11400 'value')**

```
    {this.state.tickets && this.state.tickets.issues && this.state.tickets.issues.fields && this.state.tickets.issues.fields.customfield_11400 && Object.keys(this.state.tickets.issues.fields.customfield_11400).map((issue, i) =>
    (
       <tr key={i}>
          <td> {this.state.tickets.issues.fields.customfield_11400[i].value} </td>
       </tr>
    ))}
```

**CODE WORKS ABLE TO DISPLAY THIS DATA (I'm able to fetch the 'key' value)**

```
      {this.state.tickets && this.state.tickets.issues && Object.keys(this.state.tickets.issues).map((issue, i) =>
      (
         <tr key={i}>
            <td> {this.state.tickets.issues[i].key} </td>
         </tr>
      ))}
```

**Trying this solution doesnt seem to work**

```
  { this.state.tickets && this.state.tickets.issues && Object.keys(this.state.tickets.issues).map((issue, issue_index) => (

      this.state.tickets && this.state.tickets.issues && this.state.tickets.issues.fields && this.state.tickets.issues.fields.customfield_11400 && Object.keys(this.state.tickets.issues.fields.customfield_11400).map((airlineName, field_index)=>(
       <li key={field_index}>
         Airline Name: {this.state.tickets.issues[issue_index].fields.customfield_11400[field_index].value }
       </li>
     )
   )))}
```

**Trying this solution 2 doesnt seem to work**

```
const fields = () => this.state.tickets && this.state.tickets.issues && Object.keys(this.state.tickets.issues).map((issue, issue_i) => {
  return this.state.tickets && this.state.tickets.issues && this.state.tickets.issues.fields && this.state.tickets.issues.fields.customfield_11400 && Object.keys(this.state.tickets.issues.fields.customfield_11400).map((field, field_i) => {
    return (<div> {this.state.tickets.issues[issue_i].fields.customfield_11400[issue_i].value} </div>)
  })
});

  return 
  (
   {fields()}
  );
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to your image above, `issues` and `customfield_11400` are arrays, therefor, you need to access it like this:

```
this.state.tickets.issues[issue_index].fields.customfield_11400[field_index].value
```

Since you are looping over the issues `i` is the index of the issue. You might need another loop looping over `customfield_11400`, or if `customfield_11400` only have one element you can use something like this:

```
this.state.tickets.issues[i].fields.customfield_11400[0].value
```

**Edit:**

To loop over both arrays, you could do something like this, however, you will have to add 
null checks:

```
const fields = this.state.tickets.issues.map(issue => {
  return issue.fields.customfield_11400.map(field => {
    return (<div> {field.value} </div>)
  })
});
```

Comment: Oh I just realized it, yeah, issues is an array and customfield_11400 is an array as well

Comment: So there would be 2 Object.keys.map?

Comment: Hmm can you check what I did, i did what you suggested still doesnt seem to work

Comment: Updated with an example of how you can loop over both arrays

Comment: Hmm still doesn't work, i posted how I did it similarly to what you did to loop over 2 arrays

Comment: Everywhere where you have `this.state.tickets.issues.fields` you need to change it to `this.state.tickets.issues[issue_i].fields` and where you have `fields.customfield_11400[issue_i]` you need to change it to `fields.customfield_11400[field_i]`